# Okta Angular error only in --prod build

Tags: angular, okta

We are using okta-angular (v 1.0.1) and okta-signin-widget (v 2.7.0) in an Angular 5 app.

We have some configuration in `environments/environment.ts` and `environments/environment.prod.ts` files, which is basically this but with different values for each env:

```
oidc: {
    clientId: '{Okta_ClientId}',
    issuer: '{Okta_Issuer}',
    redirectUri: '{Okta_RedirectUri',
    scope: 'openid profile email'
},
```

The above is from the prod version of the file and the values get replaced by Octopus, the non-prod version has the same keys but some hardcoded values.

In the `app.module.ts` file we bring in the deps, and create the config:

```
import { OktaAuthModule, OktaAuthService } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

const oktaConfig = Object.assign({
  onAuthRequired: ({oktaAuth, router}) => {
  // Redirect the user to your custom login page
    router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}, environment.oidc);

...

imports: [
  ...
  OktaAuthModule.initAuth(oktaConfig),
],
providers: [
  ...
  OktaAuthService,
],
```

We've added the authguard and callback component to our `app.routes.ts` file:

```
import { OktaAuthGuard, OktaCallbackComponent } from '@okta/okta-angular';
...

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'implicit/callback',
    component: OktaCallbackComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [ OktaAuthGuard ]
  },
  ...
```

We've added a login component where we create an okta signin:

```
...
import { OktaAuthService } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import * as OktaSignIn from '@okta/okta-signin-widget';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public signIn: OktaSignIn;

  constructor(
    public oktaAuth: OktaAuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.signIn = new OktaSignIn({
      baseUrl: environment.oidc.issuer.split('/oauth2')[0],
      clientId: environment.oidc.clientId,
      redirectUri: environment.oidc.redirectUri,
      i18n: {
        en: {
          'primaryauth.title': 'Please log in',
        },
     },
     authParams: {
       responseType: ['id_token', 'token'],
       issuer: environment.oidc.issuer,
       display: 'page',
       scopes: environment.oidc.scope.split(' '),
    },
  });

  const isAuthenticated = await this.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated();

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
  } else {
    this.signIn.renderEl(
      { el: '#sign-in-widget' },
      () => {
        // the success handler will not be called because we redirect to the Okta org for authentication
      },
      (err) => {
        throw err;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

}

We've added a `user.service.ts` to encapsulate some of the okta stuff like checking if the user is authenticated and storing/retrieving the access token:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OktaAuthService } from '@okta/okta-angular';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  public isAuthenticated: boolean;
  private _accessToken: string;

  constructor(private oktaAuth: OktaAuthService) {}

  async initAuth(): Promise<void> {
    this.isAuthenticated = await this.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated();
    this._accessToken = await this.oktaAuth.getAccessToken();
  }

  get accessToken(): string {
    if (this.isAuthenticated) {
      return this._accessToken;
    }

    return '';
  }
}
```

Lastly, we've updated the `header.component.ts` file to display the logged in user's email and a logout button in the app's header:

```
...
import { OktaAuthService } from '@okta/okta-angular';

import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  public userName: string;

  constructor(
    public oktaAuth: OktaAuthService,
    public userService: UserService,
    public router: Router
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {

    this.userService.initAuth().then(() => {
    this.setUserName();
  });
}

private async setUserName(): Promise<void> {
  if (this.userService.isAuthenticated) {
    const userClaims = await this.oktaAuth.getUser();
    this.userName = userClaims.name;
  }
}

logout(): void {
  this.oktaAuth.logout('/');
}
```

}

These are all of the places we've used Okta at present, and it's very much still a work in progress.

The problem is that this seems to work perfectly when running locally with a normal dev build generated with the regular `ng serve` command, but it fails miserably when running  `ng build --prod`, in this case the app does not even bootstrap, we see nothing at all in the browser, and in the console we see:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'issuer' of undefined

After debugging with sourcemaps enabled for a prod build, this error is coming from the `okta.service.j`s file inside `node_modules`. The constructor for this service requires an `auth` argument, and that is what the code is trying to get the `issuer` property from, but this is something that Angular itself should be passing to the service when it initializes it internally ready for DI.

Really have no idea what to even try given that it works without any issues in development.

Comment: Are you sure the prod environment file has the correct structure?

Comment: Thanks, yes, it's identical to the non-prod version just with different values (and `production: true` instead of `production: false`)

Comment: This is a known issue with the okta-angular library that needs to be fixed: https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/issues/176

Comment: Ok great, thanks, will keep an eye on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is with your authorization server. It is free to have access to API Access management in the preview(dev) org. but you have to pay for the feature in production org.

To check that:

Go to your production org. Okta dashboard > security > API > check if you see "Authorization Server" tab in addition to "Tokens" and "Trusted Origins" tabs

If you do not have "Authorization Server" listed. change the issuer URL to your Okta URL. So issuer =https://{org name}.okta.com

Comment: Sara, I am having the same issue. And I don't understand your suggestion above.  Basically, I have an angular app that works locally.  (I can successfully log in) It also works when I deploy to my QA environment using ng build. However, when I deploy using ng build --prod I get 400 Bad Request Error Identity Provider: Unknown
Error Code: invalid_request
Description: The 'redirect_uri' parameter must be an absolute URI that is whitelisted in the client app settings. I am using my okta preview site.  We do have a production site but I don't understand why I have to use that for QA.  PleaseHelp

Comment: Richard, your problem is different. You should copy the exact value of your redirect_url from your app and paste it Okta dashboard > application > find the application whose client id you used > General tab > edit > Login redirect URIs  > and paste the URL there.